# snowflake Need to run sql insert in loop based on column value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I have a table as below

```
id           date.         no_of Days
12           12-03-1999    30
13           12-03-1999    7
14           12-03-1999    22
15           12-03-1999    12
```

I need to create another table with one extra field as date_increment 
which will be based on given date incremented to 1 day based no_of_days.
Output will be like given below

```
id           date.         no_of Days.  date_increment
12           12-03-1999    30           12-03-1999
12           12-03-1999    30           13-03-1999
12           12-03-1999    30           14-03-1999
..           .....         ..           till 30 days
13           12-03-1999    7            12-03-1999
13           12-03-1999    7            13-03-1999
13           12-03-1999    7            14-03-1999
..           ...           ..           till 7 day
14           12-03-1999    22
15           12-03-1999    12
```

I am writing this query for snowflake which does not support loop or dynamic query.
can somebody please suggest.

Even If i use another IDE like python, I am not sure how to address this.

Answer (score 4):

One method is to use `generator()`:

```
select t.*, date + (n - 1) * interval '1 day'
from t join
     (select seq4() as n
      from table(generator(rowcount => 100)) g
     ) n
     on n.n <= t.no_of_days;
```

---

Comment: thanks a lot my friend.. only thing i had to change was instead of numrows.. i had to take ROWCOUNT